# EPERM error running tests nodejs / CodeceptJS

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, node-modules, codeceptjs

I have 4 simple logon scenarios in my feature and running them individually using the scenario.only option results in them succeeding 100% of the time.  If I attempt to run all scenarios within the feature, at some point during execution, the following error occurs.

```
[Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\RBOUR2\AppData\Local\Temp\puppeteer_dev_chrome_profile-SkYvSM\CrashpadMetrics-active.pma'] {

  errno: -4048,

  code: 'EPERM',

  syscall: 'unlink',

  path: 'C:\\Users\\RBOUR2\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\puppeteer_dev_chrome_profile-SkYvSM\\CrashpadMetrics-active.pma'
```

I am fairly new to node so am hoping someone can help me understand what this means and what area I should be troubleshooting in to try and resolve it.

I have found several articles online specific to node, reinstall with specific switches, etc., and nothing I have tried up to this point has fixed the issue.

Any assistance would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, running the codeceptjs with --verbose flag helped to clear the error.

```
npx codeceptjs run --steps --verbose
```

Once you run with --verbose flag, you can simply run without it.

```
npx codeceptjs run --steps
```